# Playing Iframe in WebView Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, iframe, webview

This code executes and does not run error but does not play the intended video meaning it has no audio or video. how can i play this video URL?

```
final WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
final WebSettings settings=webView.getSettings();
final WebViewClient webv=new WebViewClient();
webView.setWebViewClient(webv);
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play(); })()");
    }
});

webView.loadUrl("https://live.irib.ir/frame/t/tv1");
```

this code isn't play in android device but it's play fast in web browser.

how can i play this URL and resolve this problem.

Comment: What are you seeing in the console of the webview/logcat? Have you tried debugging the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,and dont forget to add INTERNET permission in manifest.

```
final WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
    webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl("https://live.irib.ir/frame/t/tv1");
```